# Variable seems to be resetting itsself

Tags: php, variables

```
$trainingStmt = $db_conx->prepare("SELECT id, groupName, date, sessDate, plan, completed, points FROM lockdownTraining
       WHERE groupName = ? ORDER BY sessDate, groupName");
    $trainingStmt->bind_param("s",$groupName);
    $trainingStmt->execute();
    $trainingResult = $trainingStmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $trainingResult->fetch_assoc()) {
        $tid = $row["id"];
        $date = $row["sessDate"];
        $newDate = date("l d F Y", strtotime($date));
        $session = htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($row['plan']), ENT_QUOTES);
        $groupName = $row["groupName"];
        $completed = $row["completed"];
        $points = $row["points"];
        $completed_array = explode(",",$completed);



        $newPoints = $points;
        //Update users table ith the new points total
        $stmt = $db_conx->prepare("UPDATE users SET ldPoints = ? WHERE username = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("is", $newPoints, $u);
        $stmt->execute();

        $sessTable .= '<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12 col-m-12" style="color:#FFF; border:1px solid black; background-color:#464B52">' .$newDate. ' - 
                            <a href="groupPage.php?g='.$groupId.'"><b>' .$groupName. '</b></a>' .$completedBtn. '<br/>Points for this session= '.$points.'
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-8 col-m-8 session">
                                    <div class="sessDiv" >' .$session. '</div>
                                    <div class="editDiv">' .$editBtns. '</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class"col-4 col-m-4">
                                <div class="attending">
                                    ' .$completedList. '
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><br/>';


    }
    $completedList = '';
```

This is a simplified version of my code.
The `$points` variable is acting weird. In the `$sessTable` It works and displays the correct amount but in the UPDATE statement, the users table shows points as 0.
If I change `$newPoints = 10;`then 10 gets displayed in the users table and the statement works.
If anyone could point out what is happening to the `$ponts` variable that would be great.

Comment: What is this function named `bind_param()`? That is not the standard PDO version of [PDOStatement::bindParam](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php()).

Comment: [mysqli bind_param](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: @kmoser It's mysqli_. It exists for years. PDO isn't the only api that offers prepared statements.

Comment: Whoops, you're right, I just kind of assumed everybody was on board with PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u is not set in your example so I presume this is set further up the code which you haven't included.

You have a while loop and let's take for example this loops 10 times.

What you end up doing is executing the SQL update statement 10 times when you should be only doing it once.

The value it finally update with is the value of the last row in the select query which looks like it happens to be 0.

Without giving example of database rows you are doing the query on then it is all speculation. If this doesn't solve the problem you still need to sort out the update issue raised.

Comment: This was perfect to help resolve my issue. @John was correct in that it is using the value of the last row called. to resolve this I had to put the update in an 'if(isset)' to pick the row that I required